# How to create a for loop to generate a range of 1110 values?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have a density (dens) array of 156510 values which comes from 141 files with 1110 values in each (141*1110=156510). These files were all combined, but I need to generate a for loop to separate each file of range 1110. Below is what I want the for loop to do, so I don't have to keep doing this manually if more files are added. What would I need to do to the for loop to get this proper separation as I have listed below?

```
dens_1 = dens[0:1109]
dens_2 = dens[1110:2219]
dens_3 = dens[2220:3329]
dens_4 = dens[3330:4439]
...
dens_140 = dens[154290:155399]
dens_141 = dens[155400:156509]
```

Comment: Why do you want each one to be in a separate variable in the first place?

Comment: @JeffUK I'm trying to do a big interpolation and need these to be separated as shown above.

Comment: Do you really want separate variables for each range group? What about a list, where, say, your "dens_3" would be `dens_groups[2]` or a dict `{"dens_3":[...]}`?

Answer (score 1):

`range` is pretty good at generating ranges. You can create a list holding each range group as in

```
[dens[i:i+1110] for i in range(0, len(dens), 1110)]
```

or a dictionary like

```
{f"dens_{i+1}":dens[i:i+1110] for i in range(0, len(dens), 1110)}
```

you could even write a quick function to grab the ranges as you need them

```
def get_range(dens, range_index):
    return dens[i:i+1110]
```